# 1px of unassosiated margin

Tags: css, margin

so I'm building a nav bar and using percentages to select the width of each element in CSS. The problem is that even though I've added up the percentages to 100% (5 buttons at 18.8%, 5 1% margin-rights and a 1% margin-left.) I still get them coming out of alignment.

[As you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrRDN.jpg) When I inspect element in chrome you can see a small piece of margin that isn't accounted for.

Here's my HTML

```
<nav class="navigation">

<ul class="navbtn section">
<li class="leftest"><a href="#whatido"><div class="link-text">What I do</div></a></li>
<li><a href=""><div class="link-text">who I am</div></a></li>
<li><a href=""><div class="link-text">Web Work</div></a></li>
<li><a href=""><div class="link-text">design work</div></a></li>
<li><a href=""><div class="link-text">Illustration</div></a></li>
</ul>

</nav>
```

And my CSS

```
.navigation
    {margin:auto;
    margin-top:50px;
    width: 50%;
    border:3px solid #c5c5c5;
    padding: 0.5% 0%;
    }

ul{
    margin:auto;
    padding:0px;
    }

ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    width:18.8%;
    margin-right:1%;
    }


li a{
    display:block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:2vw;
    color:#ffffff;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#c5c5c5; 
    }

.link-text{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

li a:hover{
    background-color:#979797;
    }
.leftest{
    margin-left: 1%;
    }
```

I'd really appreciate any help, Thank you.

Comment: Just as an aside, you can use `li:first-child` or `li:first-of-type` as the selector to which to give `margin-left: 1%;`. These are CSS 2.1 selectors, supported by all modern browsers, however IE6 didn't support them.

Comment: What is the size of your `nav`'s inner width in pixels? You may be seeing a rounding error.

Comment: The "small margin" you see is actually a collapsed line feed ("whitespace character") behind each `<li>`. One way to overcome this is add `float:left` to `li`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `display: inline-block`. Because of the white space between the list items it causes a space from four pixels.

You have several solutions:

1) remove the white space

```
<nav class="navigation">
    <ul class="navbtn section">
        <li class="leftest">
            <a href="#whatido"><div class="link-text">What I do</div></a>
        </li><li>
            <a href=""><div class="link-text">who I am</div></a>
        </li><li>
            <a href=""><div class="link-text">Web Work</div></a>
        </li><li>
            <a href=""><div class="link-text">design work</div></a></li><li><a href=""><div class="link-text">Illustration</div></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/knvzzzmw/1/)

2) add a negative margin to the list-items

```
ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left: -4px; /* added this line */
    text-decoration: none;
    width:18.8%;
    margin-right:1%;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/knvzzzmw/)

3) use float instead of inline block

Therefor, you'll also need to set an overflow on your parents, so that the list items don't flow outside the parent, and you'll need to disable the list-style.

```
ul{
    margin:auto;
    padding:0px;
    overflow: auto; /* added this line */
}

ul li{
    /* display: inline-block; remove this line */
    list-style: none; /* added this line */
    float: left; /* added this line */
    text-decoration: none;
    width:18.8%;
    margin-right:1%;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/knvzzzmw/2/)

4) use CSS tables

This way, the cells will never be bigger than one row.

```
ul{
    margin:auto;
    padding:0px;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 5px;
}

ul li{
    display: table-cell;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/knvzzzmw/4/)

Comment: Wow problem solved thank you, these were very informative :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this works better.

Add these lines to css :

```
nav.navigation ul li {
    float:left;
}
.clearfix {
    clear:both;
}
```

Also add this line to your HTML right after the last `<li></li>`:

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Live demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/c5ovhfou/